# AdMob live ads not showing up real device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I have used ads with ID that AdMob on their page give for testing the connection, and those work on both the simulator and real devices.

When I try it with test devices for the live ads, they show up on simulator (not always for banner on iPad), but on my physical device (iPad), they don't show up for either the banners or interstitials?

Why is this?

Thanks.

Code for banner:

```
func initAdMobBanner() {

    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
        // iPhone
        adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 320, height: 50))
        adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: (view.frame.size.width/2)-160, y: view.frame.size.height, width: 320, height: 50)
    } else  {
        // iPad
        adMobBannerView.adSize =  GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 468, height: 60))
        adMobBannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height, width: 468, height: 60)
    }

    adMobBannerView.adUnitID = ADMOB_BANNER_UNIT_ID
    adMobBannerView.rootViewController = self
    adMobBannerView.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(adMobBannerView)

    let request = GADRequest()
    if PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.isRequestLocationInEEAOrUnknown || PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus.rawValue == 1 {
        if PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus.rawValue == 0 || PACConsentInformation.sharedInstance.consentStatus.rawValue == 1 {
            print("no consent (show non-personalised ads) or unknown")
            let extras = GADExtras()
            extras.additionalParameters = ["npa": "1"]
            request.register(extras)
        }
    }
    adMobBannerView.load(request)
}


// Hide the banner
func hideBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
    banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
    banner.isHidden = true
}

// Show the banner
func showBanner(_ banner: UIView) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
    } else {
        banner.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width/2 - banner.frame.size.width/2, y: view.frame.size.height, width: banner.frame.size.width, height: banner.frame.size.height)
    }
    banner.isHidden = false
}

// AdMob banner available
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ view: GADBannerView) {
    if self.navigationController?.visibleViewController == self {
        let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: adMobBannerView.bounds.size.height)
        adMobBannerView.transform = translateTransform
        showBanner(adMobBannerView)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
            self.adMobBannerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }
}

// NO AdMob banner available
func adView(_ view: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    // Reposition the banner ad to create a slide up effect
    let translateTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: adMobBannerView.bounds.size.height)
    adMobBannerView.transform = translateTransform
    hideBanner(adMobBannerView)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.adMobBannerView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
}

@objc func layoutSubviews() {
    if SpeakTimerPro.hasSpeakTimerPro {
    }
    else {
        initAdMobBanner()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add your test device such as:

```
let request = GADRequest()
request.testDevices = [ "2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ] // Sample device ID
```

To find your devices ID check console output which should look like:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call:
request.testDevices = @[ @"2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b" ];
```

Comment: I am doing this - I have kept trying and got one ad on my phone a minute ago, running iOS 10. Is there just a really low fill rate or something.

Comment: if you got only 1 ad it means that most likely after the ad was seen you are not loading another ad to be displayed if you provide part of your code will be able to help you further

Comment: I have added it to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Please do note that it will take some time before newly created Ad Unit ID/s will start serving live ads.

if you are still facing an issue then please contact google admob team with your Ad Unit ID/s on which you are facing the issue.